# how to set up windows phone develop environment and using F# to develop application?

Tags: f#, windows-phone

I have already download the windows phone develop tools but I don't know how to using F# to developing the app, currently it's C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing a template for 'F# and Windows Phone' into Visual Studio makes life a little easier. If you open Visual Studio and go to Tools->Extension Manager it will open the Extension Manager dialog. From there, if you select the online gallery and type 'F# Windows Phone' into the search box you can find a couple of templates that should help you get started. Most of them were written by Daniel Mohl. His blog can be found here [Daniel Mohl](http://bloggemdano.blogspot.com/)

[image]