# Something about Visual studio express 2010 for windows phone

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, f#

I got a few question about this IDE.

First, when boot up vs2010, it displays some information below

[image: register information]

I suppose that VS2010 Express is free to use but why it tell me it has 30 days limit?

Second, after I installed vs2010 express for windows phone, I also installed F# which is downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11100)(InstallFSharp.msi). When the installation is completed I boot up vs2010 and I don't see anything like template in the new project menu, Did I miss something?

Third, in this vs2010 express for windows phone, there is no such menu  Tools->Extension, what can I do if I need to add some F# windows phone templates described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965072/how-to-set-up-windows-phone-develop-environment-and-using-f-to-develop-applicat)?

And at last, I must apologize for my English, if the question here is not clear, please leave comment and I will try harder to make it explicit.

Comment: Your English is very good. :-]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register VS Express to continue to use it. I'm not 100% sure of *why* Microsoft put this in place, but they have. You have no choice but to register if you want to continue to use it. It's not a big deal.

There is no Tools > Extensions menu in the Express editions as that is one of the restrictions Microsoft have put in place.

Comment: My guess was that this registration was put for marketing purposes. You register with your Live ID and they track who you are.